# jQuery post sends data to node.js server but the status is canceled

Tags: jquery, node.js

I am sending a post request to my node.js server as follows:

```
$.post("/admin/google",{result: result, testName: testName}, function(data){
            console.log(data);
            if(data.status === 200)
            {
                alert("Submitted successfully");
            }

        });
```

And in my router:

```
app.post('/admin/:test',
    login.required,
    function(req, res) {
      var user = req.user;
      var name = req.body.testName;
      var result = req.body.result;
```

(insert into database) and then:

```
      res.end('It worked!');
      console.log("Updated Successfully");

  });
```

The data is stored in my database successfully and I am able to get "Updated successfully" but I don't get any result back on my client and the alarm box in my client doesn't popup.
This is what it looks like in my browser network:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were calling `res.send()` in the callback after database operation. As res was not passed to the callback function explicitly, the code was not triggering.

Comment: This post request basically only inserts some data into my database and client doesnt need to get anything in in the callback. Server used to return a json {"status":200} before and I changed it to ('it worked').

Comment: It should be res.send instead of res.end I guess

Comment: I just tried different res.sed() and it all didn't work. There is something wrong with the request. Actually the whole thing works as expected on the server side and the only problem I have with this weird "canceled request" is that I am not able to show an alert popup to the user once its all done since I cant get the call back from the $.post function.

Comment: Do you get any console output about the error on browser?

Comment: Nope. I get nothing on browser. It just refreshes to the URL plus the data that was sent in query string and nothing is logged on console.

Comment: I changed my post request to an ajax request and I had the same issue and then added this into the header of ajax request: headers: { Accept : "text/plain; charset=utf-8", "Content-Type": "text/plain; charset=utf-8" }, and the error was gone but my node.js server couldnt get the data anymore which perhaps is because my data is in json format. So basically this error on my browser is generated because I havent defined a content type(?)

Comment: Hard to debug without API access. You can use curl or Postman to check the response from the server.

Comment: OK. I fixed it eventually. Your initial guess was right. I took res.status(200).send("it worked"); out of my database callback function and put it at the end of post and it worked! But I cant understand why. Why doesn't it work when res.send() is in the database callback function. I want to make sure that database gets data correctly and if there is no error then send the res.send(). Now no matter what happens it sends res.send() with my code.

Comment: Can you post the complete post block along with database callback block? I think res is not available in the database callback unless you pass it specifically.

Comment: Yea that was actually the whole problem that res seems not to be available in the database callback. But I didnt get any error on node.js even. So it was pretty hard to debug. I dont understand why res in not available in database callback though.

Comment: Just edit your answer and mention that the res.send() can not be in the callback so that I can accept your answer. Thanks for the help anyway.

Comment: Done! Unicorn dollars plss :)